# How to deal with a huge system of ODEs in Boost ODEINT?

Tags: ode, c++

I am using the C++ library ODEint, which is part of Boost, to solve an extremely large system of coupled ODEs - in particular 1975 equations with large rational functions in the coefficients. In the provided examples by the authors the ODE system is always explicitly written in the source code. Unfortunately my source code file is 37MB large, if I do it in the same manner. The compilation process is now running for 14 hours and has still not finished.

Is there another approach to cope with this huge system? Or is it possible to load the ODEs during runtime?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to redesign a bit. Instead of writing 37MB of source code, refactor it to load 37MB of data at runtime and have your rhs read this data.